# Clicar com botão direito do mouse usando Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Como faço para clicar com o botão direito do mouse, utilizando selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Em Python você vai usar a API [`selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver, duration=250)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains), ela permite automatizar interações de *baixo nível*, como movimentos do mouse, ações do botão do mouse, pressionar teclas e interações do menu de contexto.

No seu script importe ela assim:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

E após encontrar o elemento desejado vai aplicar uma ação nele, dessa forma:

```py
# driver ou browser, é a variavel que você configurou o webdriver, aqui criamos um objeto ActionChains
action = ActionChains(driver)

# seu_elemento é a variável que atribuiu o elemento encontrado, ex: find_element
exemplo = action.context_click(seu_elemento)

# Se atribuir a uma variavel você poderá executar uma ou mais vezes o menu de contexto posteriormente aplicando .perform():
exemplo.perform()
```

Note que você pode adicionar diferentes ações e executar só um `.perform()` no final, exemplo:

```py
actions.move_to_element(seu_elemento)
actions.context_click(seu_elemento)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado cara, ajudou demais!!!

Comment: bem da hora essa lib, tbm possibilita executar um script que ira agir como o click.  `execute_script("")`